# How can i make my spinner value set to the last value i selected before leaving the page when i come back in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I want to make sure when I select an item from the dropdown spinner and leave the page anytime I come back to the page the last selected item should be the current value of the dropdown

At the moment when I return to the page the first value in my dropdown is what appears in the spinner and I need it to be the last selected value from the spinner

```
override fun initialize() {
        val customerLocation = ParentActivity.getCustomerLocation()
        stateItem = ""
        areaItem = ""
        backBtn= PageView?.findViewById(R.id.backBtn)!!
        backBtn.setOnClickListener {
            ParentActivity.removeFragment()
        }

        submitLocationBtn = PageView?.findViewById(R.id.submitLocationBtn)!!
        userLocation = PageView?.findViewById(R.id.userLocation)!!
        stateSpinner = PageView?.findViewById(R.id.stateSpinner)!!
        areaSpinner = PageView?.findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner)!!

        if (customerLocation == null) {
            userLocation.text = ""
        } else {
            userLocation.text = customerLocation!!.Area + ", " + customerLocation!!.State
        }

        stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(ParentActivity)
        areaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(ParentActivity)

        areaSpinnerAdapter = AreaDropDownAdapter(areaList, ParentActivity)
        areaSpinner?.adapter = areaSpinnerAdapter

        stateSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                stateItem = stateList[p2].Name
                getArea(stateItem)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

        }

        areaSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {

                areaItem = areaList[p2].Name


            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

        }

        submitLocationBtn.setOnClickListener {
            customerLocation!!.State = stateItem
            customerLocation.Area = areaItem
            var location = customerLocation!!.Area + ", " + customerLocation!!.State
            ParentActivity.getInAppDB().saveCustomerLocation(customerLocation!!)
            userLocation.text = location
            replaceFragment(Home(), removeFragment = false, showBottom = false)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select an item in Spinner by the following code

```
spinner.setSelection(index)
```

In your case what you can do is:

1. Save the selected item maybe you can use SharedPreferences (your case: location name)
2. When come back to the same view get the selected item from SharedPreferences
3. Find the index of that item (your case: from the `stateList`)
4. Set the found index to spinner by `spinner.setSelection(index)`

It should like this

```
        stateInt = preference.getInt(customerLocation!!.State, 0)
        stateSpinner.setSelection(stateInt)

        stateSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                stateItem = stateList[p2].Name
                getArea(stateItem)
                preference.edit {
                    putInt(customerLocation!!.State, stateInt)
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: `stateItem = customerLocation!!.State                                                                                                 stateInt = preference.getInt(customerLocation!!.State, 0)                                             val editor = preference.edit() editor.putInt(customerLocation!!.State, stateInt) editor.apply() stateSpinner.setSelection(stateInt)`                                                                                  I have been getting stateInt as index 0 is there something i am not doing right? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Did you do this when selecting the item?
`val editor = preference.edit() editor.putInt(customerLocation!!.State, stateInt) editor.apply() stateSpinner.setSelection(stateInt)`

Comment: Thanks for your response so if i do this while selecting the item what do i do when i reload the page?

Comment: Edit the answer easy for you